# Class [package.classname] Not Found .Error while loading [<servlet class>] when deploying web app to glassfish server

Tags: java, intellij-idea, servlets, glassfish, java-ee-6

Earlier Everything was working fine.

After last successful running of project .I created git branch and added some packages and classes.(git is pointing to this branch only from git bash)
The class which shown in error in one of them.
I am able to find this class in target folder which maven creates and also in out folder which intelij IDEA creates .

Below is stack trace .

```
[2022-05-07T16:12:26.095+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920146095] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:26.923+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920146923] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:26.955+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920146955] [levelValue: 1000] [[
[2022-05-07T16:12:26.986+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920146986] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

  **Class [ com/attendanceapp/DAO/UserDTO ] not found. Error while loading [ class com.attendanceapp.controller.ControllerServlet ]]]**

[2022-05-07T16:12:26.986+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920146986] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.017+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147017] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.017+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147017] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.017+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147017] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.017+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147017] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.033+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147033] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.033+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147033] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.033+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147033] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.033+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147033] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.033+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147033] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.033+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147033] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.048+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147048] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.048+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147048] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.048+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147048] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.048+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147048] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.048+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147048] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.048+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147048] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.048+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147048] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.064+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147064] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.064+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147064] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.064+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147064] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.064+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147064] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.486+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [jakarta.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147486] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading application [AttendanceApp] at [/AttendanceApp]]]

[2022-05-07T16:12:27.908+0530] [glassfish 6.1] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1651920147908] [levelValue: 800] [[
  AttendanceApp was successfully deployed in 5,408 milliseconds.]]
```

**Edit 1 :**

I tried by removing UserDTO class and its usage from other classes and deployed into glassfish and everything started working .
What is going wrong with UserDTO class ?

Comment: Where is your UserDTO class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved by changing package name com.attendanceapp.DAO to com.attendanceapp.**dao**

Not sure why it worked after following naming convention for package name .

> With this I also provided everyone permission to project folder

But this should not be the cause as earlier everything was working fine without everyone permission.

Hope May this help someone and saves the days of troubleshooting.